# Why Stripe 3ds popup closes automaticly?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe-payments-js

I'm trying to intigrate Stripe 3ds flow to the project. Everything goes ok, but when you do nothing after pop-up appearing for about 5 seconds it closes automaticly.

Here is a part of my code:

```
const sendServerReq = async (id) {
    const { status, {data: payment_intent_secret} } = await purchaseRequest(id);
    if (status === 'requires_action' && payment_intent_secret) {
        const {
            error: errorAction,
            paymentIntent
        } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(payment_intent_secret);
    
        if (errorAction) {
            onError(errorAction.message);
            return;
        }
    
        await sendServerReq(paymentIntent.id);
    } else {
        return onSuccess();
    }
}
```

Comment: From just looking at this code snippet, I’m unable to explicitly suggest what the issue might be. Do you have a specific example? Are there any errors? However, as for next steps, I’d recommend that you try different browsers and see if any errors pop-up in the console. Additionally, I’d also try it on an Incognito window to see if it works as there might be extensions on your end that are blocking Stripe JS.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code? The error may not be in the code you think it is.